# is there a Google Apps Script function that tells a script to run once a specific column is populated?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm creating a script to automatically sort rows, but I don't want the rows to move until all cells in that row have been populated

I have the following code:

```
SHEET_NAME = "New";
SORT_DATA_RANGE = "A2:M999";
SORT_ORDER = [
{column: 2, ascending: true},  // 3 = column number, sorting by 
descending order
{column: 1, ascending: true}, // 1 = column number, sort by ascending 
order 
];

function onEdit(e){
  multiSortColumns();
}
function multiSortColumns(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  var range = sheet.getRange(SORT_DATA_RANGE);
  range.sort(SORT_ORDER);
  ss.toast('Sort complete.');
}
```

However, as soon as I populate column 2, the row sorts before I can populate columns 3-13.

I expect to have the rows sorted after all other columns have been populated.

Comment: `onEdit()` will run, well, *on edit* of the sheet, if you don't want it to automatically trigger every time you need to either check for a certain row to be edited in the script or run it manually.

Comment: What do you want to do in case some of the rows are fully populated and some are not? Should the sort happen only if all rows in the range are fully populated? Or should the fully populated ones be sorted and the incomplete ones ignored or placed below the others?

Answer (score 1):

You want to sort columns using an onEdit trigger on cell B2, but only if cells in row 2, columns 3 to 13, have already been populated.

The following answer addresses the logic required to execute the sort only if certain conditions are met. There are a couple of key elements to this:

- use the [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) - it makes life easier.
- get the data for row2, columns 3 to 13 (`editedsheet.getRange(editedRow,3,1,11).getValues();`) so that it can be evaluated in the loop.
- **IF#1:** test whether the edited cell was B2 (`if (editedRow == 2 && editedCol == 2){`)

  - if yes, then loop through the value range (`for (var i=0;i<rowdata[0].length;i++){`)
  - if no, then abort.
- **IF#2:** inside the loop: test whether every value exists (`if (rowdata[0][i] > 0){`)

  - if OK, then next item in the loop
  - if not OK, then abort by using `return;`
- if you get to the end IF#1, then do the sort.

---

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //so5856469701

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // get edited variables
  var editedCell = e.range;
  var editedRow = editedCell.getRow();
  var editedCol = editedCell.getColumn();
  var editedsheet = ss.getSheetByName(e.source.getSheetName());
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: Cell = "+editedCell.getA1Notation()+", row = "+editedRow+", column = "+editedCol)

  //get the data from columns 3 to 13 for the edited row
  var rowdata = editedsheet.getRange(editedRow,3,1,11).getValues();

  //do stuff ONLY if the edited cell was B2
  if (editedRow == 2 && editedCol == 2){ 
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: edited cell was in the right row or column. Continue processing");

    //loop through the data range
    for (var i=0;i<rowdata[0].length;i++){   
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: value = "+rowdata[0][i]); 

      // assumes data is numeric, otheriwse test for .length>0
      // if the value in the dat range >0, then 
      if (rowdata[0][i] > 0){      
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: greater than zero");
      }else{
        Logger.log("DEBUG: value in column "+(+i+1)+" is NOT greater than zero; script abort");
        return;
      }
    }
    Logger.log("got through the if; now run the sort");
    // to get this far, all the cells in columns 3 to 13 have values so the sort can proceed
    // insert sort code

  }else{
    Logger.log("DEBUG: edited cell wasnt in the right row or column");
  }    
}
```